/bin/sh: 1: ./make.py: Permission denied
I had this compilation error while build the onlyoffice in the docker.
Does anyone know what the reason might be? I'm using Docker started by the root user, and make.py can confirm that it has execution permission.
Here's my compile env:
1.Steps to reproduce the problem:
python3 ./automate.py server
2.build_tools base repo version:
origin/release/v8.1.0
3.Operating system:
Linux version 4.4.0-186-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-002) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) ) #216-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 1 05:34:05 UTC 2020
4.Compiler version:
the master version
5.dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV TZ=Etc/UTC
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Update the sources.list to use the mirror closet to you
RUN sed -i 's|http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/|http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/|g' /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install python \
                                    python3 \
                                    sudo \
                                    openjdk-11-jdk \
                                    openjdk-11-jdk-headless \
                                    openjdk-11-jre \
                                    openjdk-11-jre-headless \
                                    git \
                                    openssh-client

RUN rm /usr/bin/python && ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python

VOLUME ["/work"]
WORKDIR /work

# Set the default command
CMD ["bash"]

the error log output
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at be6df45... [|attr] crash &&  memory leak
Cloning into 'hunspell'...
Note: checking out '8a2fdfe5a6bb1cbafc04b0c8486abcefd17ad903'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 8a2fdfe... replace archaic &std::vector::operator[0] with c++11 std::vector::data
/bin/sh: 1: ./make.py: Permission denied
[fetch & build]: boost
[fetch & build]: cef
[fetch & build]: icu
[fetch & build]: openssl
gn gen out.gn/linux_64 --args="v8_static_library=true is_component_build=false v8_monolithic=true v8_use_external_startup_data=false use_custom_libcxx=false treat_warnings_as_errors=false target_cpu=\"x64\" v8_target_cpu=\"x64\" is_debug=false is_clang=true use_sysroot=false"
[fetch & build]: hunspell
[fetch & build]: harfbuzz
Error (./make.py): 126
install dependencies...
---------------------------------------------
build branch: release-v8.1.0
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
build modules: server
---------------------------------------------
Error (./make.py): 1
root@2148240c5bd1:/work/build_tools/tools/linux# ls

while had tried re add permission to the 'make.py' file with 'chmod -X make.py
but not working for me

You need chmod +x not chmod -x.

@kichik Sorry, that was just a typo on my part. Actually, executing chmod +X didn't have any effect too.
